# Navigation back from LockScreen

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

i have a carousel page and on each of them i have a button and the user is able to lock the page. For that i am using dependency service and that  works fine, however if i want to come back from the second page i am redirected to the first page and the page sort of "freezes". I need to be able to return to the second page of the carousel page. Can you help please?

1. I have tried INavigation but i am getting a null exception.
   2.I have also tried just override OnBackButton but that gets me back to the main page

   namespace AVAT.Droid.Renderers
   {

   ```
    [Activity(Label = "LockScreenActivity", Theme = "@style/Theme.Splash")]
    public class LockScreenActivity : FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        INavigation _navigation;
        public LockScreenActivity(INavigation navigation;)
        {
           learningPage = new LearningPage();
           _navigation = navigation;

        }
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);


            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Drawable.lockScreenLayout);

            var button = FindViewById<Android.Widget.Button>(Resource.Id.backButton);
            button.Text = "JÍT ZPĚT";
            //var index = learningPage.beforeLock;
            button.Click += delegate
            {
                FinishAndRemoveTask();
               // _navigation.PopAsync();
            };
        }



        public override bool OnKeyDown([GeneratedEnum] Keycode keyCode, KeyEvent e)
        {
            if (keyCode == Keycode.VolumeDown)
            {
                Player.GoOneSentenceBack(Article.GetTrackId());
                return true;
            }

            if (keyCode == Keycode.VolumeUp)
            {
               PlayPause();
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return base.OnKeyDown(keyCode, e);
            }

        }
    }
   ```

Comment: Since you had  used CarouselPage  , it would be better to set the value of  `CurrentPage` to navigate between items .

Comment: i have tried that, but i cant use navigation it doesnt let me. Can you advise how to get back from the screen?

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT please i have been trying for few days already

Comment: What is the means of ` doesnt let me`?